# ng-select is not working in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am facing some problem in drop down of angular js. Below is the html code

```
<select class="form-control" ng-init="projectName = options[0]" ng-model="projectName" name="projectName"  ng-options="project.name for project in projectsList track by project.id"  ng-class="{'submitted': submitted}" ng-selected="projectName" required>
 <option value="">Select Project</option>
</select>
```

all the things coming fine.

But what i want is after selecting value from drop down we submit the form and in success am getting the value what i have selected. Now i want to set this value for the drop down, how to do it ?

In jquery it works

```
$("dropdown").val('successCallBackValue');
```

but in angular how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the sucess of the form submit just set the value in the dropdown model value as,

```
$scope.projectName = yourValue; // whatever selected value you are getting.

<select class="form-control" ng-init="projectName = options[0]" ng-model="projectName" name="projectName"  ng-options="project.name for project in projectsList track by project.id"  ng-class="{'submitted': submitted}"  required>
 <option value="">Select Project</option>
</select>
```

Comment: what value you are getting after submit ?

Comment: '$scope.projectName = $scope.projectsList.name;' am doing after success but again the value is not reflecting

Comment: You need to set the whole object in you scope value $scope.projectName =$scope.projectsList;

Comment: yeah i got it after assigning the whole object to the model.. Thanks